What was the first game where "closing a door behind you" was an integrated survival mechanic?
What was the first computer\video game that has a mechanic where you had to specifically open a door to move between areas\rooms, which also included closing the door behind you as an integrated survival mechanic for the game?
For example, a rogue like dungeon crawler with multiple rooms where your character had a specific command that was used to open and close doors to allow passage between rooms, but where the act of closing a door once you had entered a room could be used to prevent enemies from the first room entering the second room, which was coded specifically so that this was a mechanic in the game.
As opposed to a game where closing a door could be used to block an enemy but where this was just a "happy accident" due to the way that the game was coded (such the same code being used to make doors and walls impassable but enemies lacking the code to open doors). Or a game where the goal of the level is to reach a door, which is then closed behind you once the level or sub level is completed?
I'm excluding games (such as text adventures) where a door has to be closed behind the player as a mandatory action. For example, failure to close the door will cause the game to end automatically as a monster will always come through and always get the player unless they close the door. As well as games where this is a single action on a specific section of the game.
Only games where you can close it a door, but failing to close the door will simply make the game more challenging, and this is a normal part of moving through the game.

From a now deleted comment by Showsni

As one early example, 1983's Moria allows you to spike doors closed behind you to prevent enemies from opening them, so this must be an intended mechanic.

Based on the now deleted conversation in the comments, the 1983 roguelike Moria appears to be the earliest where closing the door behind you was an integrated survival mechanic.

Posting this answer from the comments so it has better visibility, and can be properly voted on (it also let me clear out all the comments). Made it a wiki since I don't get rep/credit for it. @Showsni feel free to post your own answer, and I'll delete this one.
